# C++ extracting ints from a string

Tags: c++, sstream

I'm trying to extract integers from a string, for example user input could be `5ft12in` or 5'12"`.

However, the code works when my input is `5ft1in`, but not when it is `5ft12in`.

I want to loop through the whole string and extract 3 numbers, as such:

```
feet = 5 
inches 1 =1 
inches 2 = 2
```

But I cant seem to find the problem.

I think there is a way to convert the input to `stringstream` and then `peek` through the whole string using `char`, but I'm not quite sure how.

```
string feet = "";
string inches = "";
string inches2 = "";

for (int i = 0; i < height.size(); ++i) {
    if (isdigit(height[i]) && (feet.empty())) {
        feet = height[i];
    } // end if

    else if ((isdigit(height[i]) && (!feet.empty()))) {
        inches = height[i];
    }

    else if ((isdigit(height[i]) && (!feet.empty() && (!inches.empty())))) {
        inches2 = height[i];
    } // end else if

}//end for

cout << "String of feet : " << feet << endl;
cout << "String of inches 1 : " << inches << endl;
cout << "String of inches 2 : " << inches2 << endl;
```

Comment: `std::istringstream` is supposed to do so.

Comment: im really a beginner,                                                                                      
   so if i were to put it in a ss as such;                       
   istringstream iss1("5ft10in");

how would i extract the 0?


 while (ch = iss1.peek())
 {
  if (!isdigit(ch))
   iss1.ignore();
  else {
   iss1 >> i;
   cout << i << " " << endl;
   
  }

 }

 cout << i;
}

Comment: Find the positions of "ft" and "in" and look at the substrings before and between them.

Comment: i could do that but the user can also enter 5'12'' so have to go throug the whole string and return integers only

Comment: Look at the [`find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) and [`find_first_not_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) methods of `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the loop at all.

Look at the [`find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) and [`find_first_not_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) methods of `std::string`, for example:

```
std::string feet;
std::string inches;

std::string::size_type i = height.find_first_not_of("0123456789");
feet = height.substr(0, i);

std::string::size_type j = find_first_of("0123456789", i);
i = height.find_first_not_of("0123456789", j);
if (i == std::string::npos) i = height.size();

inches = height.substr(j, i-j);

std::cout << "feet : " << feet << std::endl;
std::cout << "inches : " << inches << std::endl;
```

However, this kind of pattern searching would be better handled using [`std::regex()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) instead (C++11 and later only):

```
#include <regex>

std::string feet;    
std::string inches;

std::smatch sm;
std::regex_match(height, sm, std::regex("(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+)\\D+"));
if (sm.size() == 3)
{
    feet = sm.str(1);
    inches = sm.str(2);
}

std::cout << "feet : " << feet << std::endl;
std::cout << "inches : " << inches << std::endl;
```

Or [`std::sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf):

```
#include <cstdio>

int feet, inches;

std::sscanf(height.c_str(), "%d%*[^0-9]%d", &feet, &inches);

std::cout << "feet : " << feet << std::endl;
std::cout << "inches : " << inches << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Timely Response Remy, Greatly appreciated and the code works. Im just a beginner so forums like this help me so much. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your second *if* condition, you are not checking the value of *inches*, if it is empty or not. Thus, when the "2" from your string "5ft12in" gets checked in the second *if* condition, it very much satisfies it. Therefore, resulting in again storing the value "2" in *inches*, which you actually wanted to store in *inches2*.

**Solution**:

```
string feet = "";

string inches = "";

string inches2 = "";

for(int i = 0; i < height.size(); ++i)
{

    if (isdigit(height[i]) && (feet.empty())) {         
        feet = height[i];
    } // end if 

    else if ((isdigit(height[i]) && (!feet.empty()) && (inches.empty())) {
            inches = height[i];
        }
    else if ((isdigit(height[i]) && (!feet.empty() && 
    (!inches.empty())))) {
            inches2 = height[i];
        } // end else if 

}//end for


    cout << "String of feet : " << feet << endl;
    cout << "String of inches 1 : " << inches << endl;
    cout << "String of inches 2 : " << inches2 << endl;
```